# Django Autocomplete Light widget Select2Multiple returns a string of a list instead of a list of values

Tags: django, jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I'm using Django Autocomplete Light widget Select2Multiple for a form field for tags. In `form.clean()`, the corresponding value is a string of list of the pk's of the tags, which looks like this:

```
form.clean()['tags']: "['1','2']"
```

Now, I can convert this to a list of integers and process the pk's individually but I feel like there should be a more obvious way to handle this.

Relevant field in forms.py:

```
tags = CharField(label='Tags',
                 max_length=50,
                 required=False,
                 widget=autocomplete.Select2Multiple(url='tag-autocomplete')
       )
```

PS: I can't use `ModelSelect2Multiple` as this form is for an object that hasn't yet ben created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`forms.CharField` is not designed to handle a list of values. Since you are selecting model instances, you can use [`forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField):

```
tags = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label='Tags',
                 queryset=Tag.objects.all(),
                 max_length=50,
                 required=False,
                 widget=autocomplete.Select2Multiple(url='tag-autocomplete')
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But now I'm getting an `invalid choice` error. Is there an easy way to define choices for a model?